# How to add custom methods to remote (wd)

Tags: intern

Using wd.js directly I can add my own promise chain methods as documented here:
https://github.com/admc/wd#adding-custom-methods

Is it possible to do this with the intern?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

New APIs of the underlying wd implementation like `addAsyncMethod` are not exposed. However, it’s a much better idea to create what wd calls [promise helpers](https://github.com/admc/wd/blob/master/examples/promise/helper.js) instead. Adding new methods to wd has the potential for collision with other names in the future, and can be considered analogous to modifying the prototypes of built-in JavaScript objects; using a utility function that you can pass the `remote` object to, or using a “promise helper”, ensures that you never collide with anything else and that it is clear which code is coming from wd and which code is custom to your application/testing environment.